# How can I pass some value between different Page in a TabControl?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a Window named Student.xaml ,and in this Window i have a TabControl in it, I have three pages in this tabcontrol , what I would do if I want give a value from Student.xaml to page in tabcontrol?

Comment: The tabcontrols get passed the datacontext of the parent, so they can bind to variables in the parents viewmodel already.  Have you tried it?

Comment: OK   I tried it over ths XD